# How long should database connection be open in .NET application?

Tags: .net, ado.net

This was a question asked in an interview and I was wondering whether there is any hard and fast rule to keep a connection open for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Not a single nanosecond longer than ***absolutely necessary***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is "as shortest time possible because [ado.net supports connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx) and closed connections can be reused as long as the connection string is the same"